# PhpStorm IDE header background color change

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

Is it possible to change PhpStorm IDE header background color white to any color?

[image: PhpStorm header image]

Comment: It's a standard Windows OS setting.

Comment: As already mentioned that should be whatever colour you've chosen in Windows control panel and the same for all programs that don't implement custom themes. Can you please clarify whether you want to change it for the whole system or just for PhpStorm?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the easy way you have to check whether your title bar color changes if the color is changed from personalize section on settings. Or else you have to wait till the next update...

Comment: this method for mac os. I have tried sometimes but it's doesn't work for me. even I change the registry file. but if we change windows theme setting then it will work(it's worked for me). by the way thanks for the best comment and thanks again.